# batch script to split file name and generate csv

Tags: file, split

I have some pdf files in a folder and need to split the file names to create a manifest in csv format. I am trying to achieve this with a windows batch script. The files are like this
    D:\PDF\
    100_200_test_1st.pdf
    100_300_test_2nd.pdf
    100_400_test_3rd.pdf

The csv file should be in this format

```
FILE_NAME                    FILE_NAME_WO_EXT   COL1    COL2  COL3  COL4    

100_200_test_1st.pdf        100_200_test_1st     100    200   test  1st  
100_300_test_2nd.pdf        100_300_test_2nd     100    300   test  2nd  
100_400_test_3rd.pdf        100_400_test_3rd     100    400   test  3rd
```

ANSWER

```
for entry in `ls $1`
do

echo $entry
col1=`echo $entry |cut -d'_' -f1`
col2=`echo $entry |cut -d'_' -f2`
col3=`echo $entry |cut -d'_' -f3`
col4=`echo $entry |cut -d'_' -f4`
echo $col1
echo $col2
echo $col3
echo $col4
touch col.csv

echo $col1 $col2 $col3 $col4 >> col.csv
done
```

Comment: What have you tried? What sort of scripting? What platform? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I am trying with windows batch script.

Comment: This detail should be in the question, not a comment. Show what you have tried. No one is going to write your code for you.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question in  a beautiful way. here is the unix script if anyone needs it. This group is about helping each other not testing how good they are.                                                                       
 for entry in `ls $1`
do

echo $entry
col1=`echo $entry |cut -d'_' -f1`
col2=`echo $entry |cut -d'_' -f2`
col3=`echo $entry |cut -d'_' -f3`
col4=`echo $entry |cut -d'_' -f4`
echo $col1
echo $col2
echo $col3
echo $col4
touch col.csv

echo $col1 $col2 $col3 $col4 >> col.csv
done

Comment: You should actually post the answer, well, as an answer; then it becomes some useful for others. And to reply to your slightly snarky comment this site is about helping those who help themselves. It is pretty much required that you show what you have tried. This is actually stated in the How To Ask link (or a sublink of that page) that I gave you. Requests for code to solve a specific problem, no matter how polite, are generally downvoted and ignored.